# How are default fonts set for programs like FireFox?

Tags: xorg, firefox, i3, gtk

I'm currently working on getting my first real Linux install configured and I'm having issues with programs using a font I would prefer it did not.

For example, if I look at FireFox, I can see the default font is Verdana. Where is this set?

I've used lxappearance to configure the default GTK font to be something else, am I missing something? Should I be looking for a way to configure the default xorg font?

System Info:

- **OS:** Arch-Linux
- **WM:** i3